# Visual Studio toolchain plugin in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, plugins, toolchain

few links on Internet (ex:
http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=232300575&siteSectionName=
http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums//lofiversion/index.php/t74268.html
) 
point out that there is a VS toolchain plugin for Eclipse Indigo which integrates Visual Studio (Express) into CDT. Can someone point out where to download it from?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download eclipse (preferably for c++) development. THen goto help menu in eclipse and select an option to install new software (plugins). Select all sources and search for visual studio. Select plugin and install it (you don't have to worry where it comes from).

Comment: It is called CDT Visual C++ Support. Under Programming Languages. Thanks.