# Visual Studio toolchain in Eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, toolchain

I have Eclipse Neon.2 installed for Java, however, I am working on a project that involves JNI so I have had to set up Eclipse for C++. To do this I downloaded the `Development Tools for C++` under `Help -> Install New Software`. My problem is there are no available `toolchains` available for my C++ project.

Several websites and YouTube videos have suggested that there is a Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain available, such as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046271/visual-studio-toolchain-plugin-in-eclipse-indigo) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBV1uoKqDZo), but I have had no success.

Is there a setup stage or plugin I could have missed that is causing it not to be listed?

*Setup*
Windows 10
Eclipse Neon.2
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 RC

Comment: Cross Posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b2d5d21-8233-48ea-9b8f-bb14a0d2f717/visual-studio-toolchain-in-eclipse-for-c?forum=vsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you should install either windows SDK 7, 8 or Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools.

I tested windows SDK 7 with eclipse neon.
You can find a quick installation guide [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/gclassy/3-min-Quickie-Compiling-C-Projects-using-only-the-Windows-SDK-and-the-Command-Prompt).

but I don't know what will happen with Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools.
This tools is introduced in [my blog](http://blog.naver.com/tommybee/220987383761) - even written in korean but with full of images.

Then, you can find my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936923/how-to-add-windows-sdk-to-eclipse-path/44139397#44139397).

Finally, you have two check points comparing with what you have done.

The one is

[image]

Anther one is

[image]

Comment: Hello! I am trying to use eclipse with VC++ compiler, can you show me a detailed configuration? I keep getting error messages and fixing it by trial one by one, but I don't think it's leading anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the 'another answer' link ? That was my vcc configuration with the eclipse neon.3

Comment: Yes I did, I even watched your video. I installed the Visual C++ Support plugin to eclipse, but not sure how to set up the environment variables and other configuration settings. Or should it be set up automatically via the plugin?

Comment: @Rolf See my answer.  You set up the environment variables by running the Developer Command Prompt, then launching Eclipse from there.  It's really quite simple.

Answer (score 8):

Steps to get Eclipse building "Hello World" with MSVC:

1. Install Visual Studio (should work with VS 2017, VS 2019, and maybe earlier).
2. Install Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.
3. In Eclipse, go to "Help / Install new software...".  Under "Work with...", select the CDT software update site.
4. Under "CDT Optional Features", select "C/C++ Visual C++ Support".  Install it and restart Eclipse, then close Eclipse.
5. From the Windows search/run bar, start "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" (or earlier version).  You should now have a command window and prompt.
6. Run "set", and observe that there's a ton of VS-specific environment variables present.
7. Enter the full program path to Eclipse (e.g. `C:\Users\drodgers\eclipse\cpp-2019-12\eclipse\eclipse.exe`), and hit Enter.  You're now running Eclipse again, but with all the VS environment variables present.
8. Create a new C++ Managed Build project.  Enter a project name, select "Hello World C++ Project", and select Microsoft Visual C++ as the toolchain.  Finish creating the project.
9. In the main source file, you should see an orange squiggle under `#include <iostream>` and red squiggles under `std`, `cout`, and `endl` because Eclipse doesn't know where to find all the include files.  Let's fix that.
10. In Project Explorer, right-click on the project name, select "Properties", then select "C/C++ General / Paths and Symbols".  With the "Includes" tab in view, select "Add...", you'll get an "Add directory path" dialog.  Click "Variables...", wait a moment, then select "VCToolsInstallDir", which will fill `${VCToolsInstallDir}` in the dialog (or just type it).  Then append `/include` so that it reads `${VCToolsInstallDir}/include`.  (Backslash works too... but see below.)  Check the "Add to all configurations" and "Add to all languages" boxes.  Your dialog should look like this:

[image: Setting the include path to VC include files]

11. Click OK, then click Apply and Close.  If you're prompted to rebuild the index, say Yes.  The orange squiggle for the include should go away, and once the index is rebuilt, the red squiggles should go away, too (do a manual index rebuild if necessary - right-click project, select "Index / Rebuild".
12. Right-click your project, and select "Build".  It should now build successfully., like so:

```
21:12:43 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project wibble ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi "/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\\\include" /nologo "/Fosource\\wibble.obj" "..\\source\\wibble.cpp" 
wibble.cpp
link /debug /nologo /OUT:wibble.exe "source\\wibble.obj"

21:12:44 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.594ms)
```

13. Verify that you can run your new executable by browsing to your project location, going into the "Debug" directory, launching a command prompt, and running the EXE that's there.  You should see "Hello World" appear in your console window.
14. To further simplify your launch process, create a subdirectory under your user directory (e.g. `C:\Users\drodgers\batch`), create `eclipse.bat` containing the full path to Eclipse, and then edit your environment variables to add the new directory to your user variables' "Path" setting.  Now when you run the Dev Command Prompt, you only have to type `eclipse` to launch Eclipse.

(Disclaimer: I can't take full credit for this answer, because I found the guts of it [here](https://blog.agramakov.me/2018/07/08/configure-visual-studio-toolchain-on-eclipse/).  But I couldn't find a SO post that offered this solution, so I'm posting it myself.)

**EDIT**: Been playing a bit more, and there's some quality of life stuff that needs to be added.  For whatever reason, MS doesn't include `ctype.h` or a number of other "standard" headers in its main include directory, so items like `isxdigit()` will be flagged red as `Function isxdigit() could not be resolved`.  To fix this:

1. As referenced in a [comment to the accepted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258311/cannot-open-include-file-ctype-h-no-such-file-or-directory), for VS 2017 or 2019, you should install the "Windows Universal CRT SDK" component using the VS Installer app.
2. Close Eclipse, relaunch the VS 2019 Developer Command Prompt, and relaunch Eclipse.
3. In your Eclipse C++ project, under "Paths and Symbols", specify these two directories: `${VCToolsInstallDir}/include` and `${WindowsSdkDir}/Include/${UCRTVersion}/ucrt`.  Note I used forward slashes; they work fine with Eclipse on Windows systems.  If I use backslashes in that second path instead, Eclipse starts invoking substitution escapes and you won't get the right path, so don't do that.

Now you shouldn't have any unresolved symbols in your editor (at least for standard C/C++ stuff).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid this is a very old question so I'm not in the position to test this anymore but hopefully it will help someone else and dropped you a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Run Eclipse from Developer Command Prompt. If you added all include paths, but *<windows.h>* could't be resolved and *fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winapifamily.h'* occurs then to All configurations and All languages (checkboxes) **Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Include directories -> Add...**

- Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
- Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared

and don't forget **Project -> C/C++ Index -> Rebuild**

If there is *fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'* and ucrt.lib in **Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Linker (Link) -> Libraries -> Additional Libpath (/libpath) Add...**

- Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86
- Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86

or (x64, arm, etc...) for Configuration: All Configurations

Also know, that you could't debug with CDB & [through the years Eclipse keeps brand](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1110298/)